# Is something like template inheritance possible in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a `<draftable-input>` component that's starting to grow. It has four different "types": text, textarea, slider, wysiwyg. This is a textbook case of inheritance.

The core functionality - letting the user edit the input as a 'draft' and then save or discard their changes - is common among all four types. The only difference is a single portion of the template.

Currently I use it like this:

```
{{#draftable-input
  type='wysiwyg'
  ...}}

{{#draftable-input
  type='textarea'
  ...}}
```

and so on. The component itself is ~100 lines. I some CPS and a method that do different things based on `type`:

```
isWysiwyg: Ember.computed.equal('type', 'wysiwyg'),
isSlider: Ember.computed.equal('type', 'slider'),
isTextarea: Ember.computed.equal('type', 'textarea'),
isText: Ember.computed.equal('type', undefined),

selector: function() {
  var selector;
  switch (this.get('type')) {
    case 'wysiwyg':
      selector = '.redactor-editor';
      break;
    case 'textarea':
      selector = 'textarea';
      break;
    default:
      selector = 'input'
      break;
  }

  return selector;
}.property('type'),
```

The other ~85 lines are generic.

The template is ~60 lines, with about half of it looking like this:

```
{{#if isWysiwyg}}
  {{redactor-input value=copy
    buttons=buttons
    placeholder=placeholder
    escape-press='cancel'
    errorMessage=errorMessage}}
{{/if}}

{{#if isText}}
  {{input value=copy
    class='form-control'
    placeholder=placeholder
    escape-press='cancel'}}
{{/if}}
```

and the other half is generic.

So, my spidey senses are tingling to refactor this into four separate components. One abstract DraftableBase, and the four specializations. This works perfect for my JS code - I'd get to delete the code that switches on type, and each subclass would simply need to specify its selector:

```
export default DraftableBase.extend({
  selector: '.redactor-editor'
});
```

The problem is, the templates. How can I share the 30 lines across each subclass? As far as I know, there's no way to do something like "template inheritance" with subclasses. So, I don't know what to do. If I subclass, I get to drop all the ridiculous type-switching code, but then I'll be duplicating a lot of Handlebars.

Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried to refactor those repeated elements into partials and then dynamically load a partial based on controller property?

Comment: I have done something similar but would prefer to keep everything within the associated pod... as far as I know, partials only work if they live in `/templates`

Answer (score 2):

There isn't such thing like template inheritence but you can refactor your code using partials. You need to generate partial name dynamically

```
App.MyComponentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  partialName: function() {
    return 'my-component-partial/' + this.get('type');
  }.property('type')
});
```

to each place in your template that is different for each type

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
       {{my-component type="textarea"}}
       <hr />
       {{my-component type="input"}}
   </script>
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-component">
       common things
       {{partial partialName}}
       common things
   </script>

   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="my-component-partial/textarea">
      <p>text area here</p>
   </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="my-component-partial/input">
      <p>input here</p>
   </script>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/gijecukuxu/1/

Of course you can create base and child views as well.